# Getting broken pipe error in the following program

Tags: java, hive

```
import java.util.List;    
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServerException;    
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive;    
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive.Client;    
import org.apache.thrift.TException;    
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;    
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket;    
public class Hive_demo_02 {
/**
* @param args
*/
static TSocket transport;

static Client client=null;

private static Client getClient(String hiveServer, Integer hivePort)    
{

  final int SOME_BIG_NUMBER = 999999993;    
    try {
        transport = new TSocket(hiveServer, hivePort);    
    transport.setTimeout(SOME_BIG_NUMBER);    
    transport.open();    
    TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);    
    client = new ThriftHive.Client(protocol);    
    System.out.println("Connection is established");    
    return client;    
    }    
    catch (Exception e) {    
    e.printStackTrace();    
    return null;    
    }    
    }

}
private void show_databases(Client c1)

{

    if(c1!=null)

    {

try {

try {

    c1.execute("show databases;");

} catch (TException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

}

List<String> li = null;

System.out.println("hai");

try {

li = c1.fetchAll();

System.out.println(li);

System.out.println("hai");

} catch (TException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

}

System.out.println(" *** The Databases List *** ");

for (String string : li) {

System.out.println(string);

}

System.out.println(" -------------------------------- ");

Client c2=c1;

}
finally{

}

    }

}

private void create_databases(Client c1)

{

try {

c1.execute("create database IF NOT EXISTS jdbc_demo");

} catch (HiveServerException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

} catch (TException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

}

System.out.println(" *** jdbc_demo Databases is created *** ");

System.out.println(" -------------------------------- ");

Client c2=c1;

}

private void use_databases(Client c1,String db_name)

{

try {

c1.execute("use "+db_name);

} catch (HiveServerException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

} catch (TException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

}

System.out.println(" *** Changed Database to "+db_name+" *** ");

System.out.println(" -------------------------------- ");

Client c2=c1;

//return c2;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String HIVE_SERVER = "localhost";

Integer HIVE_PORT = new Integer(54310);

Client client = getClient(HIVE_SERVER, HIVE_PORT);

Hive_demo_02 obj=new Hive_demo_02();

obj.show_databases(client);

System.out.println(" Before Creating the Database jdbc_demo ");

obj.create_databases(client);

System.out.println(" After Creating the Database jdbc_demo ");

obj.show_databases(client);

System.out.println(" Changing to jdbc_demo Database ");

obj.use_databases(client,"jdbc_demo");

transport.close();

}

}
```

I am getting Broken pipe socket exception in this program. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: It's very hard to follow what the program is doing as there is no indentation. Also, please provide more help for potential answerers. What is the program supposed to do? How does it fail to do that? What have you tried and what have the outcomes been?

Comment: It is trying to connect to Hive server and try creating, displaying and changing database in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Set the port number as 
export HIVE_PORT=10000
then start the hive server using 
./hive --service hiveserver